# Which is more efficient Multiple Tables or Unified Tables in a mysqli database

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

**I'm trying to create a database but having trouble deciding on which process will be more efficient in the near future, the process of the database is as follows, users will be able to upload 10k data per session and the these are the methods i'm thinking of doing right now.**

```
Method 1:
Putting all of the session data to one table for EX:

Session 1 : 10k
Session 2 : 10k
...
Session 20: 10k
Total Data on table: 200k


Method 2:
Session 1 : 10k Allocate to -> Table 1
Session 2 : 10k Allocate to -> Table 2
...
Session 20 : 10k Allocate to -> Table 20
Total Data on table: 10k / per table
```

*what would be more efficient in the long run mysqli database wise and speed wise?*

**Multiple Database Tables or Unified Tables**

Comment: Depends on the used storage engine and workload (writes and reads).. disks RAID config.. in short we need more information.

Comment: What does "database wise" mean?  The amount of disk space used?